# Curvature of a 2D discrete curve

Tags: differential-geometry, discrete-geometry

Suppose one has a discrete plane curve in 2D, such that the curve is composed entirely of connected straight line segments. Clearly, the usual definition of curvature does not apply, as this curve is not smooth.

However, is there a curvature definition one could use, that would converge to the usual definition as more and more line segments were used to describe a smooth curve? That is, for a discrete plane curve, at each vertex point, our discrete curvature should be defined such that at the limit of the smooth curve, the new curvature at the vertex, should be the curvature of the curve at that point.

1. Is such a definition possible?
2. If it is, are there standard definitions for this discrete curvature?
3. Is more than a single definition even possible?

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

Comment: This is a common problem in my area (multiscale modeling). I spent almost a year trying to either find a solution (for just my single case) in the literature or come up with something myself. I didn't find anything. The point was to identify a well-defined meaning of the curvature of a discontinuous profile, or rather of a statistical ensemble of such profiles that somehow average out to a smooth profile. So this is a familiar but difficult issue.

Comment: @Ian - I know this area is well studied on discrete meshes, and that Gaussian curvature can be defined there. I haven't been able to find anything on 1D meshes though.

Comment: *Shrug* I just know that rigorously passing from a discrete model to a continuous model involving curvature is very difficult. At least in the piecewise $C^1$ case (like in your figure, and unlike in my problems) you have an arclength measure that is not highly singular.

Comment: You could discretise the curvature equation:

$k=\left|\frac{dT}{ds}\right|$ ; 

$k(i)=\frac{
\frac{r(i+1)-r(i)}{|r(i+1)-r(i)|}-\frac{r(i)-r(i-1)}{|r(i)-r(i-1)|}
}{\frac{|r(i)-r(i-1)|+|r(i+1)-r(i)|}{2}}$

where k(i) is the curvature of the ith point and r(i) is the position of the ith point.

(also: should this be answer or comment?)

Comment: @AidanConnelly The problem is that this does not have the appropriate continuity properties as you approach the smooth curve: the points whose neighbors are both on the same line segment have no curvature but somehow they should still have curvature in the limit. This is related to the "false proof" that $\pi=4$ obtained by "approximating" the circumference of a circle by repeatedly "cutting corners" out of a unit square, obtaining a sequence of figures that resemble the unit circle but all have perimeter $4$.

Comment: In the book Discrete Differential Geometry by Bobenko (and some other authors that I can't remember now unfortunately), one of the sections is devoted to find discretizations of the usual notions of curvature for curves and surfaces in space. Nonetheless, I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: The domain of $k(i)$ would have to be integers, that is it gives the curvature on the ends of the line segments.

Comment: @AidanConnelly That doesn't fix the problem. Idea 1: define the curvature only at the kinks. That fails because the continuous curve has curvature all the way along. Idea 2: define the curvature at non-kinks to be the average of the curvatures at the two kinks involving the line segment. Then the result does not converge in the desired manner (the curvature of the smooth curve is continuous). I'm not sure about idea 3: define the curvature at non-kinks to be the *weighted* average of the curvature at the two kinks involving the segment by giving more weight to the closer kink.

Comment: @Ian Hello, are you still interested in the problem? Did you have a look at the book *Digital Geometry, Geometric Methods for Digital Picture Analysis* by Reinhard Klette and Azriel Rosenfeld?
 http://www.citr.auckland.ac.nz/~rklette/Books/MK2004/

Comment: Has anyone looked at the discrete curvature definition in these slides: http://ddg.cs.columbia.edu/SIGGRAPH05/Didactic.pdf ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heuristically what I would do is, for each polygonal approximation:

1. Decide on a value for both the *direction* and a *curvature* at each vertex, by fitting a circle through it and its neighbor vertices on each side.
2. Along each of the straight segments, assign a curvature as a quadratic function of arc length, such that (a) it agrees with the values a the endpoints that you have already decided on, and (b) its integral over the entire segment is exactly the different in assumed *direction* between the vertices.

If your vertices always lie *on* the original smooth curve, as is the case in your illustration, this ought to converge nicely (that is, locally uniformly) towards the true curvature.

For some applications it may work just as well simply to interpolate linearly in step 2. Using a quadratic correction has the advantage that you can integrate it to find a continuously varying *direction* at each point on the segment, which can be used to simulate shading, bouncing off the curve, and the like.

Comment: I like this, as it aligns with the intuitive meaning of curvature, where the lengths of the segments should inversely effect the curvature.

Comment: @nbubis The lengths don't directly affect the curvature. Suppose you have two segments of different slopes, so you have three points, one of which is a corner. You add a point in the middle of each segment (it need not be at the midpoint, just anywhere in the middle). The curvature in the sense of Henning's answer at the corner point is *still the same* even though the lengths of the segments have changed.

Answer (score 4):

Curvature of a smooth curve can be interpreted as the rate of change of the *angle* that its tangent vector makes with a fixed direction. So, if you have a piecewise smooth curve, each singular point contributes (in a natural way) the exterior angle [if you have incoming tangent vector $\mathbf v$ and outgoing tangent vector $\mathbf w$, you take the angle from $\mathbf v$ to $\mathbf w$]. This works just fine with a piecewise-linear curve: It has curvature only at the corners, and the total curvature is still the rotation index of the curve.

Indeed, for a piecewise-smooth simple closed plane curve $C$ oriented counterclockwise, the Hopf Umlaufsatz becomes $\int_C \kappa\,ds + \sum\epsilon_i = 2\pi$.

Comment: This is the true curvature of the piecewise linear curve. How can we treat the curvature of the piecewise linear curve as approximating that of the continuous limiting curve?

Comment: It works perfectly with my definition. Note that in your approximations, the exterior angle approaches 0 as your PL approximation approaches the curve (in any reasonable sense).

Comment: That can't be right. Again as I said in the comments, think of the vertical/horizontal "approximation" of a circle given by cutting corners out of a sequence of figures starting with a square. It has *more* curvature than a true circle, so that its circumference is larger than the pointwise limit. How can we reconcile that? Or alternately what regularity assumptions can we make about the approximants to prohibit it? (Also my comment had an error, if one approximates a unit circle by such "cut squares" then the approximants have perimeter 8, not 4.)

Comment: @Ian I would argue that this is because your example only converges pointwise and not uniformly to the circle.

Comment: @SvenPistre That's not quite right because it's not clear what the domain where "uniformity" should be interpreted is. The actual problem is that they are not $C^1$ in the arclength parametrization and indeed eventually these discontinuities accumulate to become dense. But this is exactly the kind of thing that you usually desire to do in situations like the OP: to "fill out" the arclength of the approximants with corners that are just a tiny distance apart.

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure what you're doing. But with the way I said to do it, any convex polygon will have total curvature $2\pi$. I don't know why you're talking about perimeter. ... By the way, there's an analogous thing that works with polyhedral surfaces and cone angles. For that, see Exercise 13 on pp. 90-91 of [my differential geometry text](http://faculty.franklin.uga.edu/shifrin/sites/faculty.franklin.uga.edu.shifrin/files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf). The curve result is Exercise 12 on p. 34.

Comment: You are right that convexity helps matters...is the OP assuming convexity?

Comment: @Ian: As I just edited, it's far more general than that. All you need is a simple polygon. I just threw in the convexity because you were thinking of approximating a circle by convex polygons.

Comment: The global curvature evens out as you say, but without some additional assumption you cannot recover the correct local curvature because the approximants can be constructed to have "fine structure" that washes out under a pointwise limit.

Comment: You need more than pointwise convergence, of course — some sort of Lipschitz or a.e.-$C^1$ convergence.

Comment: This doesn't align with the intuitive notion of curvature: For a single vertex, the segment lengths don't influence your defined curvature. One would expect that as segments become longer, the curvature would decrease.

Comment: Totally irrelevant. You can smooth the corner out in as little space as you want.

Comment: @nbubis Indeed for any single vertex the contribution of the curvature should only have to do with the discrepancy between the slopes of the segments connected to it, not the lengths of those segments. This is not really surprising, curvature is essentially a "second derivative" type quantity.